# How to convert the below string to URLDecode and assign to UILabel - Objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I would like to know how to convert the below string to URL Decode string and assign it to UI Label.

```
%3Col%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09The+Gift+Card+shall+be+redeemable+at+3M+Car+Care+outlets.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09Customer+can+visit+www.carcarestores.3mindia.in%2FAppointent.aspx+or+call+1800-300-+22-300+to+book+an+appointment+and+redeem+the+Gift+Card+at+the+outlets.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09The+Gift+Card+is+valid+for+a+period+of+12+months%28365+days%29+from+the+date+of+activation+and+shallexpire+if+not+availed+within+the+validity+period.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09This+card+can+be+redeemed+for+any+treatment+or+product+depending+on+the+value+loaded+onto+the+card+apart+from+flexi+Car+packages.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09Gift+Cards+cab+also+be+reedemed+partially%2C+as+many+times+as+user+wishes+to%2C+till+its+balance+is+consumed+or+the+Gift+Card+expires.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09Gift+Card+is+neither+transferable+nor+can+be+exchanged+for+Cash%2FCheque+or+any+equivalent+either+in+part+of+in+full.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09If+the+Gift+Card+is+stolen+or+lost%2C+neither+will+a+new+Gift+Card+be+issued+nor+will+the+money+be+reimbursed.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%3C%2Fol%3E%0D%0D%3Cp%3E%0D%0D%09%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fp%3E
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using [removingPercentEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409569-removingpercentencoding)  to decode your string

```
NSString *yourString = @"%3Col%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09The+Gift+Card+shall+be+redeemable+at+3M+Car+Care+outlets.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09Customer+can+visit+www.carcarestores.3mindia.in%2FAppointent.aspx+or+call+1800-300-+22-300+to+book+an+appointment+and+redeem+the+Gift+Card+at+the+outlets.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09The+Gift+Card+is+valid+for+a+period+of+12+months%28365+days%29+from+the+date+of+activation+and+shallexpire+if+not+availed+within+the+validity+period.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09This+card+can+be+redeemed+for+any+treatment+or+product+depending+on+the+value+loaded+onto+the+card+apart+from+flexi+Car+packages.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09Gift+Cards+cab+also+be+reedemed+partially%2C+as+many+times+as+user+wishes+to%2C+till+its+balance+is+consumed+or+the+Gift+Card+expires.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09Gift+Card+is+neither+transferable+nor+can+be+exchanged+for+Cash%2FCheque+or+any+equivalent+either+in+part+of+in+full.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0D%09%09If+the+Gift+Card+is+stolen+or+lost%2C+neither+will+a+new+Gift+Card+be+issued+nor+will+the+money+be+reimbursed.%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0D%3C%2Fol%3E%0D%0D%3Cp%3E%0D%0D%09%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fp%3E";
NSString *decodeString = [yourString stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
```